# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in AndroidX in obfuscated app

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation, androidx, android-r8

I've got a really weird error and I need an expert's eye to dig more into this issue.

In releasing my application in play store, I got some crashes in Crashlytics that seems to happen only on a few devices, right after a first installation of the application.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method f(Landroid/content/Context;)Landroidx/core/app/n; in class Landroidx/core/app/n; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.core.app.n' appears in base.apk)
   at com.example.app.core.di.AppModule$Companion.provideNotificationManager(AppModule.kt:88)
   ...
```

The use of `f` and `n` shows that app is obfuscated with r8 and a proguard rule.

The source code where the crash is happening looks like this:

```
@Provides
    fun provideNotificationManager(context: Context): NotificationManagerCompat =
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)
```

`NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)` comes from `androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat`. This class is obfuscated during build time.

We are using version `1.8.0` of `androidx.core:core-ktx` dependency.

[Release note of this version](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core#1.8.0) does mention changes made on `NotificationCompat`.

Nothing about androidx has been added in `proguard-rules.pro`.

These lines are added in **build.gradle**

```
release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

- Why can we got a `NoSuchMethodError` exception whereas this method can be found when I decompile the apk?
- Why can we got a `NoSuchMethodError` exception whereas error message says that *"declaration of 'androidx.core.app.n' appears in base.apk"*?
- Why this error does not occurs on all devices (and they are many of them)?
- Why this error is happening only after a first installation of the application (based on logs we got)?
- Is this related to the fact that it concerns a `static` method ?
- Do we need to add a rule in proguard file to keep all classes of `androidx`?

Thanks,

Comment: This sounds like a issue that is best handled through the R8 issue tracker. You can open a new issue at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=326788.